# Problems with a Simple Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a very simple method for my programming class and ran in to an issue I can't find the resolution for in my notes.

You see I'm supposed to create a method that generates an array of an arbitrary length that has each consecutive value be a multiple of the last (interest rates). The problem is I can't find why my code doesn't work, it compiles but doesn't print what I'd like.

Instead of printing an array with something like (made up values):

`[1, 5, 25, 125]`

It prints out obscure text like:

```
[D@64bd4e3c or [D@7041a12f
```

Can someone please help? Below is a link to an image of my code:

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieNn2.jpg)

[image: My Code]

Comment: For future reference, paste your code in here. The link may not work for those who are at work. And clicking the link is too much effort :P

Comment: you shouldnt post images of your code on StackOverflow; instead, paste the code in, and we can actually edit them. pictures need to be transcribed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
System.out.print(Statements)

is essentially System.out.println(Statements.toString()) ;
```

It prints the address that Statements points to.

```
[D@64bd4e3c" or "[D@7041a12f" As you may have observed changes because the location of the array in memory changes. Hence the address is different or may be the same if reused.
```

You need to iterate through `Statements`.

In pseudocode:

```
for i to Statements.length
  print Statements[i]
```

Here is a nice [link](http://www.javaclass.info/classes/java-array/array-examples-demonstration-and-code-snippets.php) to help you.

Comment: So what you're saying is System.out.print 'ing an Array the way I have only points out the address of one of the values as opposed to the values themselves? Also that I need to make a for statement that states each row space of the array to print each row?

Comment: @Luke yes, you need to use a for statement and combine them into a string, etc.

Comment: No, it isn't printing an array. It is calling .toString() implicitly which prints the address of where the Array is living/stored in memory. 
And yes you need a for loop to print each element.

Comment: Thanks guys, y'all are great! Would up vote you if I had the permissions =P

Comment: @Luke No problem. Whenever you can (and accept if you like for community whatever). Good luck.

Comment: @Luke, don't forget to accept the answer which best meets your requirements when you can ;)

Comment: Sorry, new, is it enough to just click the checkmark? I want to make sure cred is received where cred is due.

Answer (score 4):

For printing arrays in java, use:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(Statements));
```

Hope this helps!